# Convert string to numerical - PySpark operation on a json file

Tags: json, sum, pyspark

I ran into a problem converting a column of "string" into numerical.

I was able to perform the following 2 commands:

```
people=sqlContext.read.json("C:\wdchentxt\People2.json")
people.select('name',people.age+1).show()
```

but I got error for the following, because 'age' is "not a numerical column".
How to converge age column from string to numerical?

```
people.groupBy('gender').sum('age').show()
```

I was particularly confused because `people.age+1` was successful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cast function in PySpark dataframe

```
df.select('gender',df.age.cast('int').alias('age')).groupBy('gender').sum('age').show()
```

Comment: thank you!  This is much more involving than I thought. Do you know why the following line worked correctly?  people.select('name',people.age+1).show().  Here if I could add 1 to people.age, then it must be an numerical number, right?